# While loop for renaming duplicate name

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement some code that will automatically rename a users inputted name if the name they enter has already been submitted. I have it working to some extent, however the issue is that if the loop iterates over more than once, then you end up with the name being renamed to something like this 'Clothes (1) (2) (3)'

Here is the code that I have at the moment:

```
if nameLength == 0 {
        fade()
        entryWarningLabel.text = "Please enter a transaction name."
    } else if arrayObject.paymentsArray().containsObject(transactionName) == true {
        if autoAdjust == true {
            var index = 1
            while arrayObject.paymentsArray().containsObject(transactionName) == true {
                transactionName = "\(transactionName) (\(index))"
                index = index + 1
            }
            popToVC()
            enterButtonCode()
        } else {
            fade()
            entryWarningLabel.text = "You already have a transaction named '\(transactionName)'."
        }
    } else if nameLength > 0 {
        popToVC()
        enterButtonCode()
    }
```

The first else if is the relevant part of the code.

How can I rename transactionName without ending up with multiple values in brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using `transactionName` that may have been modified by the prior iterations of the loop. You should use the original `transactionName` instead:

```
let originalName = transactionName;
while arrayObject.paymentsArray().containsObject(transactionName) {
    transactionName = "\(originalName) (\(index))"
        index = index + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew the reason for the issue but wasn't sure how to go about fixing it.